# How to use predicate builder to return active users who satisfy certain search condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I am using [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build a dynamic EF predicate.

I want to return all Active users whose firstname or lastname matches the requested search term. Here is what I have tried but but I always get all of the active users... it means the search is not narrowed down by the search term:

```
string searchTerm = "John"; // <-- comes from user
predicate = predicate.And(u => u.IsActive == true);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(u => u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm));
    predicate = predicate.Or(u => u.LastName.Contains(searchTerm));
}
```

Comment: More: The part `(u => u.IsActive == true)` can be replaced with `(u => u.IsActive)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break down your logic into a simple boolean expression -

```
x = IsActive == true
y = FirstName match
z = LastName match
```

Your logic is `x or y or z`.  If the user is active, they will get returned.

You are wanting `x and (y or z)`.  Inside your `if` statement, something like -

```
predicate = predicate.And(u => u.FirstName.Contains(searchTerm) || u.LastName.Contains(searchTerm));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I would have `predicate = predicate.And(u => u.IsActive == true);` and then add your line in the `if` clause?

Comment: yes.  Also FWIW, you don't need `== true` on a boolean expression.  So `(u => u.IsActive)` (unless IsActive is a nullable boolean)